# What happens if I sail into a whirlpool?

Tags: sunless-sea

Numerous whirlpools dot the zee, appearing as named locations on maps. I have confirmed by sailing close to one that they do suck you in, but I've not dared to actually sail into one. What happens if I do?

Comment: There's at least one [special whirlpool that will kill you](http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/Dathooley%27s_rage).

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything unique about Dathooley's Rage in the game files, or any evidence that any whirlpool is capable of OHKOing a ship with at least a reasonable amount of hull left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that whirlpools will slowly damage your hull, which is explained rather extensively [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sunlesssea/comments/2wsjzx/whirlpools/). You can get stuck in a whirlpool if your engine isn't strong enough, but on the plus-side: enemy ships can also have this problem.

[This user on the steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/304650/discussions/0/610573009241234274/)  was letdown that the whirlpools only slowly damage your hull.